# How to fix td border issue?

Tags: css, html, html-table

You can see my page at [keeptheinternetpure.com](http://keeptheinternetpure.com)

I have some nested tables, and I have some images displayed in some cells, but for some reason the border is messed up and the background color extends beyond the image and border. Does anyone know why this would be? It isn't effecting any of my other cells I have, only effecting the sidebar.

The style sheet is located at [keeptheinternetpure.com/standard.css](http://keeptheinternetpure.com/standard.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the size of the other column. The height of the first td is adjusted by the browser to match the one of the second td (otherwise you wouldn't have a proper table). If you just want the picture having a black background, and not the whole cell, then remove the class `textbgone` from your first td and keep it only in the `img` tag.

Comment: EDIT:
the issue is my border - I want the background of the border to be black, but not the background color of the table itself. How would I go about doing that?

EDIT:
Would I have to define the width and height manually?

Comment: Is there a way to make the border of my other cells inside instead of outside?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the background of the border, the area inside the border?

Comment: I have a dashed border, and I want the space between the dashes to be black

Comment: If you remove `textbgone` from the td and keep everything else as it is, the spaces between the dashes are black, so I'm not sure if I understand what you mean.

Comment: Hmm...but now they aren't lined up nicely - how would I fix that?

Comment: I can remove the border of the textbox to fix the lining up, but then I don't have a border, which is unfortunate.

Comment: The problem is the `line-height` CSS property. If you set it to 0 for the table, it won't add extra space under each picture, which affects the background of the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this : http://jsfiddle.net/H6p6s/

```
img {border:dashed yellow;background:red}
```